# Using Open WIFi Newtorks With No Password

Tags: wifi

Please forgive my ignorance, but are there any security issues with connecting to a known (safe) WiFi network with that requires no password?

Am I right in thinking that any other network that uses the same SSID and no password, that came in range of my device would result in my device auto-connecting to it? Potentially allowing me to unwittingly connect to a rogue network?

Comment: Is your concern about general risks or about connecting to another wifi network?

Comment: Why do you believe that an open Wifi network can be known-safe? Safe from what?

Comment: The network is provided by my corporate offices. I am not worried about their connection, rather unintentionaly connecting to bad actor using the same SSID.

Comment: What could a bad actor do on a wifi with the same SSID that could not do on the corporate Wifi?

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. The duplicate linked to is over 5 years old and has no answers. It's a reasonable question.

Comment: Is that not the question I am asking? Perhaps I am not being clear:
I connect to a corporate open WiFi. No password, easy access. I go somewhere else where someone has set up their own WiFi with the same SSID. Does my device automatically connect to that WiFi?

Comment: @user3102815 - Depending upon settings, yes it could very well automatically connect to the other network with the same SSID. How much of a security concern this might be depends upon additional factors, including your subsequent use.